# Kali linux aircrack

Tags: kali-linux, internet

I have AirPort Extreme network card and when I try to use airmong-ng on kali linux in a virtual machine this does not work. I know I need a usb-network card if I want to  make this work but if I boot kali from a cd or usb do I still need this because then I won't be sharing internet with my macbook and it saves 30 bucks.

Comment: It's never wise idea to run hardware operations via a virtual machine. Try Kali LiveCD instead that should operate fine. If you really want to use it within a virtual machine you'll need to bridge it across correctly.

Comment: The bootable OS should work fine, like @Paul said. Sometimes a VM has trouble sharing hardware with its host OS, but when only Kali is using the network card everything ought to go smoothly.

Comment: https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/wireless-n-m2-ngff-card-v2-tpe-m2ncrd2

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not all WiFi cards / drivers work well on Kali.
Especially for monitoring... Please have a look on [this link](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/01/08/recommended-usb-wireless-cards-kali-linux/)

> A common problem in pentest distro such as Kali or BackTrack Linux is
>   when users trying to use a card which is not supported or there just
>   isn’t a supported driver. Most of the following cards are priced below
>   $50USD and they take care of a massive headache and saves time to
>   troubleshoot driver issues rather than investing time to actually do
>   something.

In my case, I had to purchase a TP-Link WN722N as I experienced too many issue with my PCI-E WiFi